# Need to throw the user an error if a case is true

Tags: php, postgresql, error-handling, subquery

I have a sports games picks application that goes by weeks. Right now if you pick a week that you already picked I get a php error. Instead of that I would like to just display a message to the user saying you have already picked for this week.

Heres the error that I get when I pick for the same week

```
  ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_record_pkey" 
  DETAIL: Key (username, week_no)=(john, 1) already exists
```

Heres my code

```
 <?php
            session_start();
            require_once("dbconnect.php");
            $flag = 0;
            $row = 1;
           // $weekest = $_POST['weekNum'];    

            $result3 = pg_query($conn, 'INSERT INTO demo.user_record VALUES (\''.$_SESSION['username'].'\','.$_POST['weekNum'].',0,0)') or die(pg_last_error());
            //echo $_POST['picks0'];
            //echo $_POST['picks1'];
            for($row=1;$row<=$_POST['numPicks'];$row++){


                    $pickName = "picks" . $row;
                    echo $pickName;
                    if($_POST[$pickName] == "picks$row")
                    {
                    $pick = $_POST['Tname'.$flag];
                    $flag+=2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $flag++;
                    $pick = $_POST['Tname' . $flag];
                    $flag++;
                    }
                    //echo "error2";        

            $result2 = pg_prepare($conn, "myquery".$row, 'INSERT INTO demo.user_picks VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)') or die(pg_last_error());
            $result2 = pg_execute($conn, "myquery".$row, array($_SESSION['username'],$_POST['weekNum'], $row, $pick)) or die(pg_last_error());
                     echo "finished";
        }
   ?>
```

Comment: What is table description `user_recor`

Comment: Inserting values into the user_record table

Comment: I think you are beginner? run below query in mysql terminal and paste output here. `desc user_record`

Comment: I think I just need to add an if statement somewhere

Comment: You'll need to first run a SELECT query to see if an entry already exists for the user/week. If it returns a result, display your message; otherwise, run your INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

First, the function [pg_query() returns FALSE on error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php). You need to check for that. There are code examples in the linked documentation.

Second, your code is prone to SQL injection. You shouldn't use pg_query() for this kind of problem. You should use pg_query_params() instead. (Same link. Search for "String interpolation of user-supplied data is extremely dangerous".)